# Creating an array for each month after today

Tags: php, date

I cant find a way to create array for each month after this current one.

```
            <?php 
                $month = 07; 
                $year = 2016;
                $end = date('Y');
                for($i=0;$i<=$end-$year;$i++){
                    $from = 1;
                    if($i==0)
                        $from = $month;


                    for($y=$from;$y<=12;$y++){
                        if($year==date('Y') && $y > date('m'))
                            break;

                        $a = $year+$i.'-'.$y;
                        $months[$a] = $a;
                    }
                }
                krsort($months);
            ?>
            <?php echo Html::dropDownList('month_year',$month_year,$months,array('class'=>'form-control'));?>
```

I want to get a dropdownlist that looks something like this

2016-09

2016-08

2016-07

For each month that comes. Starting date should be 2016-07. And the top value should be current month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a start and end date and loop through them:

```
$start    = (new DateTime('next month'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('+24 months'))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("Y-m") . "<br>\n";
}
```

I use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [`DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) as this is the cleanest way to do this and handles DST and leap year natively.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/611684)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, i just modified start to be fixed and end to be current month. Thanks for the solution :)